# how do I use upstart, instead of cron, to start a single instance of a job which should always respawn?

Tags: command-line, cron, services, scripts

How do I script the following bitcoin/dogecoin/etc [cpuminer](https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer) command:

```
/home/digger/cpuminer/minerd -o stratum+tcp://doge.pool.webxass.de:3333 -O <user>.<worker>:<worker_password>
```

to execute in `cron` so that if, and only if, `minerd` is **not** running?

My current cron script

```
* * * * * digger /home/digger/webxass
```

results in *way* too many `minerd` processes:

```
top - 12:32:00 up  4:55,  3 users,  load average: 17.45, 13.71, 7.98
Tasks: 141 total,   2 running, 139 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.1 us,  0.1 sy, 72.7 ni, 27.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:    502268 total,   463344 used,    38924 free,    25200 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free,   325140 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                
14335 digger    20   0  374m 3540 2452 S  10.3  0.7   3:29.42 minerd                  
14344 digger    20   0  374m 3544 2452 S  10.3  0.7   2:29.48 minerd                  
14352 digger    20   0  374m 3540 2452 S  10.3  0.7   1:59.50 minerd                  
14527 digger    20   0  374m 3540 2452 S  10.3  0.7   0:39.83 minerd                  
14362 digger    20   0  374m 3540 2452 S   5.2  0.7   1:39.50 minerd                  
14373 digger    20   0  374m 3540 2452 S   5.2  0.7   1:24.51 minerd                  
14491 digger    20   0  374m 3540 2452 S   5.2  0.7   1:12.55 minerd                  
14500 digger    20   0  374m 3540 2452 S   5.2  0.7   1:02.55 minerd                  
14511 digger    20   0  374m 3540 2452 S   5.2  0.7   0:53.98 minerd                  
14519 digger    20   0  374m 3540 2452 S   5.2  0.7   0:46.49 minerd                  
14535 digger    20   0  374m 3540 2452 S   5.2  0.7   0:33.82 minerd                  
14544 digger    20   0  374m 3540 2452 S   5.2  0.7   0:28.38 minerd                  
14552 digger    20   0  374m 3536 2452 S   5.2  0.7   0:23.39 minerd                  
14560 digger    20   0  374m 3536 2452 S   5.2  0.7   0:18.78 minerd                  
14568 digger    20   0  374m 3536 2452 S   5.2  0.7   0:14.51 minerd                  
14576 digger    20   0  374m 3540 2452 S   5.2  0.7   0:10.51 minerd                  
14584 digger    20   0  374m 3540 2452 S   5.2  0.7   0:06.77 minerd                  
14592 digger    20   0  374m 3540 2452 S   5.2  0.7   0:03.25 minerd                  
    1 root      20   0 26952 2644 1340 S   0.0  0.5   0:01.11 init                    
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0            
    5 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H            
    7 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0            
root@doge:~# killall minerd
root@doge:~# cd
```

Perhaps it's just as efficient to run hundreds of little `minerd` processes, I don't know, but I would rather just one or two.  Two probably makes more sense.

see also

http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.ubuntu.user/271280

Comment: I'll look into upstart.  Whatever works, I didn't know of any other way to start a process in the background (daemon?).

Comment: Why are you using `cron` for a daemon that should be started by [SysVinit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto#Traditional_Sysvinit_and_Before_Ubuntu_6.10) or more recently [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) (or systemd)?

Comment: @DavidFoerster good suggestion, upstart looks good, I'll modify the question.  If you can give me an idea, I just want something like:  http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#if-job-is-not-currently-running  so that  it's always running.  Not sure what the config file should look like, nor exactly where to put it.

Answer (score 1):

`cron` is not the right tool for the task. Ubuntu now uses Upstart for services and tasks. You can create a self-respawning service with the [`respawn` stanza](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn).

Answer (score 0):

From the [cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#if-job-is-not-currently-running), this looks like the right idea:

```
dig_coins stop/waiting
dig_coins start/running, process 9474
```

Only I'm not exactly sure where to define `dig_coins`.

Comment: The dig_coins Upstart job definition would go in `/etc/init/dig_coins.conf`